# Use tcpListener and sslstream to serve https request

Tags: .net, https, tcplistener, sslstream

Is it possible to serve https request using TcpListender and sslStream in .net?

Answer (score -1):

Yes， it can be done using sslstream

Comment: Please show some working code or give hints, "Yes" is not a sufficient answer.